# Where do I find all of Oracle Apex's properties?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am a relatively new user of Oracle Apex, and as such I have done quite a bit of research about how to achieve everything I want to do with my application. I understand that I will have to use Javascript in order to achieve some of my goals with the application, and I have found a lot of sample code on the Internet that is applicable to Apex. However, I'm wondering if there is a place online or on Apex itself where I can find all of the "properties" of the elements in an application?

As an example, here is some Javascript code I found online for how to disable column resize on interactive grid:

```
function(config) {  
   config.defaultGridViewOptions = {  
   resizeColumns: false  
}  
return config;  
}
```

How would I know about the "defaultGridViewOptions" property or the "resizeColumns" property?

I want to be able to write my own Javascript code for my application, but I don't know the names for all of the properties. Is there somewhere online that I can view these properties, and possibly their definitions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far is the Interactive Grid is concerned there isn't much (any?) documentation yet, but [this series of blog posts by John Snyders](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/18/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-1/) is very helpful.

Comment: It's not just the interactive grid that does not have the documentation, a while back I was having to figure out how to do a specific thing in a tree region; and there was no documentation either ...
I had to look directly at the javascript file resposable by that widget.
Maybe these links might help:
[Ajax javascript files: https://proda.mediemr.net:8443/i/libraries/apex/ ], [Interactive grid javascript file: https://proda.mediemr.net:8443/i/libraries/apex/widget.interactiveGrid.js ], [Interactive grid examples: https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet ]